# Is there any low cost way to Calibrate my display?

Tags: color, monitor, calibration

I'm using Apple cinema display model number A1316 27 inches. I think it is from 2010.

I'm making User Interface for mobile app and we also plan to make some marketing collateral (some printed brochurse and packaging etc.)

Should I calibrate my cinema display (it has never been calibrate before)? if I should, should I use X-Rite ColorMunki Display (http://www.xrite.com/colormunki-display) or I should go for X-Rite i1 (https://www.xrite.com/i1solutions-color-management). I do not have much money will X-rite ColorMunki Display be sufficient enough for my work?

Or is there other brand or product that is better and cheaper than these product?

is the spectracal brand also suitable for my work which model? The Datacolor S5X100 Spyder5EXPRESS also interesting. Which one to choose?

Comment: Hi user3270418, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your question. If you want to know more about the site, please see the [help] or ping one of us in the [chat] once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Comment: You may be able to rent a device from a photography equpiment supplier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you *should* calibrate, always.

As for what calibration hardware to use, that's largely a matter of preferences. But *any* calibration hardware is better than none. You really can't go terribly wrong with any of them.

I use the Xrite i1, but that's just my preference.

Comment: My cinema display got a bit yellowish on the white colour, will this calibration machine helps to fix the yellowish problem?

Comment: If it's not a hardware issue, probably. I've been using the same Cinema Displays for over 10 years.... calibrated every few months. No issues here. You can just eyeball calibrate with the System Preference, you know? That may fix the yellow issue to a degree.

Comment: Using dim ambient lighting allows you to lower the brightness of an LCD, which extends it's life.   If you've been running your display at default brightness for ten years, it may have more color shifts after calibrating/profiling than a monitor that's been profiled at a lower brightness.  It would still be better than no profiling at all, however.  I like to make a greyscale image with a radial fountain fill from black to white to see how many rings of color appear where they should be neutral.  It gives me a good gauge of how well linearized the calibration of  the display is.

Comment: I check my monitors @digijim they are still good. I'd replace them quickly if there was even the slightest doubt. I also don't run them at full brightness, mainly because that's always been too bright. So there is a little room to move if needed.

Comment: Sorry, that was directed at @user3270418, Scott.  A shift in default white appearance is a sign of degradation, in my experience.  Plus, I'm pretty sure I couldn't teach you anything new.  :)

Comment: Oh I'm sure you could, @digijim :)

Comment: Sorry for my poor english, in conclusion do i have to buy the new monitor ? ^^" or the calibration machine will be sufficient for my applcation?

Comment: @user3270418 there's *no possible way* anyone on any message board or forum can tell you that. We'd have to be in front of the monitor. Try eyeball calibrating with the System Preferences (use "advanced mode") and see if that helps at all. If it does, calibration hardware may help further. It is possible you just have a corrupt color profile and recalibrating will help that.

Answer (score 3):

If you're planning to do printing and packaging, you should necessarily get a Spyder5PRO or Spyder5ELITE, as the EXPRESS version won't compensate the ambient light of your room with its ambient light sensor.

This is important as the contrast will be adjusted correctly for your working room. Additionally, ensure that you have a constant, darkened room light throughout the day where you work with your calibrated monitor.

Comment: I would not recommend spyder due to the way they license the software speparately from the hardware. This is extremely annnoying and can ulitimately leave your hardware unusable because the software for using it is not a driver but a separately licensed software. I think this business model needs to die.

Comment: The x-Rite tools also read ambient light, just so you know.

Comment: I don't see the problem, I can install the software on as many computers as I want to...

Comment: @RubenCarmona except when they discontinue the old verdion