# How to ensure color fidelity of the same file on two computers?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, color, raster

What is the safest way to ensure that raster image exported from illustrator will be displayed correctly (in term of color fidelity) on another computer ?

I know that there will always be some inter-individual difference in term of color perception. However, I have experienced several difference between color perception of the same file on two computers. The differences were so important that some details were not visible..

Thank you in advance

Comment: I'm no expert, but I did visit one of my old company's contract manufacturers that made signs and labels. They had a special location in their office, with very specific kinds of ceiling lighting. This, plus the the things mentioned in the answers, helped them keep the screen representation(s) and the print representations as close as possible to each other.

Comment: Their monitors had *calibration stickers*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There isn't much you can do, unfortunately. The safest you can do is to make sure the image is in the sRGB color space when exported. The majority of people will be viewing it on monitors within that color gamut. Then just hope the people viewing your image don't have poorly calibrated monitors!

If you know the target device it's a bit easier. A few of my clients use 4k Adobe RGB monitors for their trade show, so I always make sure I know the target device so I can account for this when proofing for other monitors.

If they are viewing your image from the web, also keep in mind that even if they have a correctly calibrated monitor, some browsers are not color managed.

To keep it simple, sRGB everything. :)

Comment: I will check if my images are in sRGB, thank you for your answer !

Comment: Anytime, good luck!

Answer (score 5):

The answer is a color calibrated workflow.

> on another computer...

Depends on how "random" that computer is. Let me explain.

The only thing you can control is the computer you can control.

1. Have a good enough monitor.
2. Take one of these: https://www.datacolor.com/photography-design/ or https://www.colormunki.com/ There are several models to choose from.
3. And configure your Illustrator correctly with the proper color profiles.

---

4. If you can control the "other" computer, do the same.
5. If the other computer is a random computer from your client, and you have no access to it, or there is no IT department that can calibrate it, you can not do anything.

---

Take a look at this: [Why should I calibrate my screen?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/96308/why-should-i-calibrate-my-screen/96323#96323)

> One man is driving and listens on the radio:
>
> "A drunk man is on the highway driving on the opposite way!"
>
> And the man says, "One? there are a lot of them!"

The only thing you can do is control your side of things.

Comment: I disagree with this part "The only thing you can do is control your side of things.". Educating the other people involved on the other end is possible, and very important. If colour fidelity is important to you, assume they've got no clue and tell them how to get their own system setup.

Comment: On the other part depends on how random is your client. Read Point 5. Rephrasing, if there is an IT department that can calibrate it, please, do.